# Dropzone check max. files PHP side

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, dropzone.js

I'm sending some files through the [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com) to my PHP server. I'm having a problem validating the max files being sent PHP side. Even though I will use the `maxFiles` param for dropzone.js I would like to make sure nothing odd is being sent more times than needed. The main problem is that dropzone can send the file per POST request, so I cannot simply `count($_FILES)` because there is always gonna be 1.

So I decided to store the temporary uploads in the database using the session id and the field hash and select the count of uploads by that hash.

Unfortunately, that doesn't work as intended, since another request is being sent too fast.

Code is:

```
if ($request->ajax())
{
    $hash = md5(Session::getId() . '_myupload');
    $count = DB::query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM temp_uploads WHERE hash = ?")->param($hash)->execute();
    echo $count; // 0

    // Store the file

    DB::query("INSERT INTO temp_uploads (key) VALUES (?)")->param($hash)->execute();
    $request->file('myupload')->store('uploads');
}
```

I'm uploading two files and the second request is being sent before the INSERT query even finished executing.

How can I properly validate the max files from multiple request in PHP?

Comment: You should set restrictions on maximum size uploading in settings Web Server (Apache/Nginx). It will be more securable. Otherwise try to use: `$_FILES, size()`

Comment: I will, however the 'maximum size uploading' wont affect the files count being sent. Eg. maximum size = 2MB and max files = 2, so basically 4 files weighing 500~ kB could be sent each per request.

Comment: Interesting problem. How about instead of using the session, put a unique ID in the form, and POST it along with each file.  Then use the same approach you have above to check each new upload against the number matching the POSTed id.

Comment: @Don'tPanic `$hash` is basically a unique ID for that certain upload field. The thing is, no matter what unique ID I will use as the POST request is faster than database query hence, even 20 POST requests can be made until the database record is finally stored.

Comment: How about limiting `parallelUploads` on the client side, so only 1 or a small number of files are uploaded in parallel, giving your requests/DB time to record each?  Or disable `uploadMultiple`?  http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration-options

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is to maybe look at Laravel's throttle middleware, to limit the number of requests that form can make.

Comment: @Don'tPanic `uploadMultiple` is disabled (thats why it does send one file per request - otherwise I could use `count($_FILES)`). But anyways, thats still only a javascript solution. If it comes to javascript I could do a lot, including setting an interval delay for each upload but thats not the javascript case and I'd like to validate it in PHP so that some bad users couldn't change the dropzone settings through the console and such. Oh and btw. I'm not using Laravel for this, even though methods are similar :)